# How would I insert an image into this text element in a "text adventure" in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I have this section of code, I have gotten it to work as text that appears changes when you click a button. It's based off of some code from a "choose your own story" sort of thing. (Source: https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/JavaScript-Text-Adventure)

Everything works except the image that I really don't know how to add. I've been stuck on it for days because I can't find anything for this specific element.

How would I get an image to load inside this element so that it appears and dissapears a long with my text and buttons?

```
const textNodes = [{
        id: 1,
        text: "I did it all for you.",
        //here is where I have attempted to use a variable to insert an image, with 20 being the height (I am very inexperienced)//
        imageOne: 20,
        options: [{
            text: '>>',
            nextText: 2,
        }]
    },
    {
```

I've also tried this which copies the format of my option buttons, but it doesn't seem to work either:

```
image: [{
            **url: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80"
        }],
```

Here's what I have in my html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="OP1.0c.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script defer src="OP1.0j.js"></script>
    <title>Text Adventure</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div id="story"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="pictures">
        <image class="image"></image>
    </div>
    <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
        <button class="btn">Option 1</button>
        <button class="btn">Option 2</button>
        <button class="btn">Option 3</button>
        <button class="btn">Option 4</button>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: [The `<image />` element is deprecated/not recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/image); honestly, this question is the first time I've ever seen it. Use the [`<img/>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img) instead.

Comment: Stack ate some of my code, but here's where I declared the variables for the code that used it:  //here is where I have set my image variable with a url//

var imageOne = [{
    imgUrl: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1544526226-d4568090ffb8?ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxzZWFyY2h8Mnx8aGQlMjBpbWFnZXxlbnwwfHwwfHw%3D&ixlib=rb-1.2.1&w=1000&q=80'
}]; dude am i using comments wrong?

Comment: Oh, i always forget that, let me try that, edit: did nothing

Comment: Are you passing the element a `src` attribute that points to the image?  I see your `<image/>` element doesn't seem to have anything that tells it where the image resource can be fetched from...